# Integrating large and complex modules using PRISM 4.0

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

My team is planning to integrate some WPF applications that are fairly large and are developed by separate teams. For instance, most of them are layered applications with several DLLs (data access, services, etc.). They also use different IoC containers internally such as Castle Windsor and Unity.

The main Shell is based on MEF.

We are thinking to have one shared module with all the types used in the communication between the modules. Each application would be a module loaded by the Shell's bootstrapper and would export one view, which would be loaded (using view discovery) in a specific region in the shell.

I wonder if you've ever faced a similar scenario and what issues you had if any?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats will work and this "main module" usually called Infrastructure and not really a module but shared library.

Everything else you described is pretty standard setup.